# How can I count the result of a for each loop?

Tags: php

I have a text file from where I parse all lines with the label `blue`:

```
foreach($colors as $row) {
   if (array_key_exists('blue',$row)){
      echo "blue:".$row['blue']."<br>";
   }
}
```

My result:

```
blue:sky
blue:ocean
blue:orchid
```

Now I want to count my result. Do I have to put the result into an array before counting?

I tried `count($colors);` but then of course I get the number of all colors in my text file. I also tried `count($row['blue']);` but then my result is `0`.

Comment: Can you post the structur of $colors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either put the result in an array and print out `count()` or increment a variable:

**Solution 1:** (storing the values in an array)

```
$result = array();
foreach($colors as $row) {
   if (array_key_exists('blue',$row)){
      $result[] = $row['blue'];
   }
}
// after your foreach loop
echo "Results: " . count($result);
```

**Solution 2:** (incrementing a variable)

```
$i = 0;
foreach($colors as $row) {
   if (array_key_exists('blue',$row)){
      $i++;
      echo "blue:".$row['blue']."<br>";
   }
}
// after your foreach loop
echo "Results: $i";
```